# How to install packet on Linux Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-releases

I want to run my .net 5 app on a Linux app service that has specific libraries (for example ibnss3-dev).

I have pipeline for build:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  wwwrootDir: 'Web/wwwroot'
  dotnetSdkVersion: '5.0.x'

- script: |
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y libnss3-dev
  displayName: 'Dep install'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core SDK $(dotnetSdkVersion)'
  inputs:
    version: '$(dotnetSdkVersion)'


- script: 'echo "$(Build.DefinitionName), $(Build.BuildId), $(Build.BuildNumber)" > buildinfo.txt'
  displayName: 'Write build info'
  workingDirectory: $(wwwrootDir)
  
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Restore project dependencies'
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/Web.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build the project - $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--no-restore --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    projects: '**/Web.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Publish the project - $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    projects: '**/Web.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    arguments: '--no-build --configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
    zipAfterPublish: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  condition: succeeded()
```

And a release with Azure App Service deploy (Task Version 4)

How should I do it? I tried the following solutions, but non of them works:

1. Release Post Deployment Action with sudo (kuduPostDeploymentScript.sh: sudo: not found)
2. Release Post Deployment Action without sudo ([error]E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied))
3. Add script step in the pipeline

I can run install command manually via ssh but I'm looking for an automated method.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y libnss3-dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this question. As you already discovered you should replace your command `"dotnet web.dll"` with sh script where you first install dependencies and then run your web.dll with dotnet CLI.

Comment: It didn't work. As I know, the pipeline is used for restoring and compiling the app, not for the destination machine, am I wrong?

Comment: Yeah. That's correct. But why do you need this on runtime? Is your app not self sufficient after compilation?

Comment: I use a nuget package that needs these libraries installed on the machine.

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/q/64895608/2347999?

Comment: Thanks, the link was very helpful. Could you please update your answer? It works for me with creating .sh file and instead of "dotnet web.dll" I set it to "depInstall.sh". Inside the sh and after installation I ran web.dll with dotnet command

Comment: I just edited my reply. I'm super happy you solved your issue!