# Post-build actions in Python/Linux webapp do not run

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have a Django-based web app deployed from Github, running in Python 3.9. The app deploys and starts successfully.

I need to add post-build actions to complete the deployment; the exceeding common Django task of running "manage.py". Following the [general](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/main/doc/configuration.md) and [python-specific](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#customize-build-automation) docs I have added the an app setting of
POST_BUILD_SCRIPT_PATH=postbuild.sh

There is a shell script, postbuild.sh in the root of my app, which runs fine if I SSH into the running container. The expected behaviour is that after deployment, this should run, and output to the deployment log. Neither of these things happen.

I have tested the app setting POST_BUILD_COMMAND with a very simple echo, and that does nothing either.

Can you tell me either what I need to do to make these app settings work, or suggest an alternative method of running the post-build script?

Please note that this is a Linux app using Oryx, so answers concerning Windows/Kudu like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64895608/run-post-deployment-action-on-azure-app-service) aren't related.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you asked your question over [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/705883/post-build-actions-in-pythonlinux-webapp-do-not-ru.html) as well. Your setting needs to be set to a relative path, `/postbuild.sh`.