# Azure Web App showing default page or Application Error after successful python deployment

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-webapps, azure-appservice

Developed a Python  Flask Web App and connected to Azure SQL Database. The code is running successfully in local.

But when deployed to Web App in azure (Linux based web app ) either i am getting default page or the "Application Error :If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources."

Not sure where i am going wrong. ANy help is deeply appreciated.

Below is the code.

```
    import textwrap
import pyodbc
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

# DataBase Connections

driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}' 
server_name ='sample-web'
database_name ='sample-web'
server = '{server_name}.database.windows.net,1433'.format(server_name=server_name)
username = "ramazdemo"
password = "Password123"
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database_name+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

# Code

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def index():
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userdetails = request.form
        name = userdetails['name']
        email = userdetails['email']
        crsr: pyodbc.Cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        crsr.execute("""INSERT INTO users (Name,Email) VALUES(?,?)""",(name,email))
        crsr.commit()
        crsr.close()
        return 'success'
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

[image: App Service in Azure]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help is deeply appreciated. T

Comment: If you need further help, pls let me know.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Answer (score 1):

**Troubleshooting**

**The best way to find the problem is to query the log.**

1. Check ODBC driver( or you can reinstall drivers follow my answer in below post).

   [How to access ODBC Driver on Azure App service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64640016/how-to-access-odbc-driver-on-azure-app-service/64674606#64674606)
2. Redeploy your web app by another way. The reason is to rule out that the current tool has bugs or environmental factors that cause the release to fail unrecognized.

   [Deploy your Flask app on Azure in 3 easy steps](https://medium.com/@nikovrdoljak/deploy-your-flask-app-on-azure-in-3-easy-steps-b2fe388a589e)